# Audio plays in background but no sound Cordova 3+ IOS

Tags: ios, html, audio, cordova, background-audio

I'm playing a mp3 file. I used cordova 3+
I'm using

```
snd = new Media(source,onSuccess,onplayError,mediaStatus);
snd.setVolume(current_volume);                      
snd.play();
```

Everything goes well. Then I set these in **info.plist**

```
Application does not run in background - NO
Required background modes:
Item0 - Audio...............etc.
```

Then I tried this

```
if ([resourceURL isFileURL]) {
    [[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
    audioFile.player = [[ AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithContentsOfURL:resourceURL error:&error];
} else {
    NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:resourceURL];
    audioFile.player = [[ AVAudioPlayer alloc ] initWithData:data error:&error];
}
```

This is found from here http://www.joeldare.com/wiki/play_an_mp3_audio_stream_in_phonegap

Though I found that sound.m file wasn't there as described. I found that file in plugin folder. And those lines were near line no. 363

Then I tried to play the audio. Next I pressed the home button. No sound came from the iphone emulator. After that I preesed the app icon again, app ui came to front and sound can be heard as if it was playing all along. Means suppose I have pressed the app icon after 1 minute from the home button press, then the song is playing from 1 minute currently. So song was actually playing but sound can't be heared during that period after pressing home key. Hope I explained it properly.

Can anyone please tell me what I'm missing? I want the sound to be heared even after home key is pressed or phone gets locked or display gets off. Please help.......

Also **if I use html5 audio player**, what I've to do to handle this 'home key press' problem to play the audio after minimization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First,DO those things that I wrote in question. Then import AVFoundation into your `AppDelegate.m` `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Then add the following to `application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions`

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
BOOL ok;
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
ok = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
```

Found from here https://github.com/devgeeks/ExampleHTML5AudioStreaming

And

> TEST IN REAL DEVICE, NOT IN SIMULATOR. BACKGROUND AUDIO DOESN'T WORK
>   WITH SIMULATOR.