# Cordova + iOS - How to play audio file when app is running in background?

Tags: android, ios, cordova, audio, background

I have Cordova app which is playing selected sounds. I would like to play sounds continuously when app is leave by user and another one is coming to foreground.

How can i do it please for iOS platform? On Android it works fine in default.

Many thanks for any advice.

Update:

I did following:

**plist.info**

```
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <string>UIBackgroundModes</string>
    <key>audio</key>
```

**AppDelegate.m**

```
/**
 * This is main kick off after the app inits, the views and Settings are setup here. (preferred - iOS4 and up)
 */
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions
{
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    BOOL ok;
    NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
    ok = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
```

But with the same result.

Answer (score 0):

First,DO those things that I wrote in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23732463/audio-plays-in-background-but-no-sound-cordova-3-ios). Then import AVFoundation into your `AppDelegate.m` `#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>`

Then add the following to `application:(UIApplication*)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary*)launchOptions`

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
BOOL ok;
NSError *setCategoryError = nil;
ok = [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:&setCategoryError];
```

Found from here https://github.com/devgeeks/ExampleHTML5AudioStreaming

And

> TEST IN REAL DEVICE, NOT IN SIMULATOR. BACKGROUND AUDIO DOESN'T WORK
>   WITH SIMULATOR.

Comment: Hello, please, see my udpated question. Background playing by your code is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it using this plugin:
https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-background-mode